# Spotlight Significant Energy Usage

Tags: mojave, hardware, battery, spotlight

The battery life on my MBP 2017 has recently decreased to around 3-4 hours after lasting around 8-9 hours for the past 9 months. Activity monitor also shows spotlight having an average energy impact of 115. Most people in the past had been attributing this issue to Mojave's 'new' spotlight indexing although this doesn't seem to be the case for me as the problem has only arisen in the past week. My MBP has also been experiencing freezes during this time so could this decrease in battery life be correlated with some underlying hardware problems? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Jerry. Welcome. What have you tried besides Activity Monitor? Have you looked for malware? Restarted the computer? Tested in a new user? Safe Mode? Turned off Spotlight indexing?

Comment: Also, have you started using any new software or updated any apps recently? Do you use any file syncing services like Google Drive or DropBox? When did you upgrade to Mojave?

Comment: Hi Geren. I do not use any syncing services and I believe I upgraded to Mojave several months ago. I've looked for malware, restarted my computer and added several folders to the 'privacy' list on spotlight to prevent indexing however it still seems to be using significant energy :/

Comment: You can try putting your full user directory in the *Privacy*, see if energy usage stops. If not, turn off all categories of spotlight. Removing it from Privacy will cause it to rebuild.  @JerrySmith

Comment: Adding Macintosh HD to the privacy list seemed to fix the issue! Thank you very much